# Operation on different data types

Tags: python

I've been trying to figure out what is the result of, for example,  adding `int` and `float` parameters together, or `log2(x) + abs(y)`, `sqrt(x) + True`, etc. How does Python deal with those kind of operations, and why? Where can I find information about this?

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#numbers? *"operators with mixed type operands convert the integer operand to floating point"*

Comment: thanks @jonrsharpe but what about the build in functions ?

Comment: What precisely do you mean? E.g. `sqrt` always returns a `float`, whether it gets an `int` or `float` - is that what you're asking?

Comment: something like this for example sqrt(floor(1.3)) // 2 or ("44" and ceil(1.12))

Comment: Well `//` always returns an integer, that's the point of it, and using `and` involves [truthiness](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). I'd recommend reading the Python docs and tutorial and returning if you have a more specific question.

Comment: Thanks for the info :)

Comment: Try debugging that expression in [thonny](http://thonny.cs.ut.ee/) to see how it breaks it down.

Comment: @AlexHall thanks  i did understand it :)